# Hibernate Executes the failed insert query multiple times after catching the exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I tried to insert a record into the database and the action failed with "UniqueConstraint Validation". I handled this exception using a catch block. Everything is good until here

Next - there is another action which tries to insert to a different table. Before executing this action - Hibernate still has the old action (failed DB insert) as part of the action queue and tries to execute it one more time. It fails with same Unique constraint error.

I do not want to clear the session as it would clear the cache and other details as well. Is there any way to clear the associated action query which was failed before?

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSgCv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either don't insert something which violates constrains or loosen the constrains. Database constrains should *not* be handled but avoided.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Consider a use case for maintaining a batch load of records which needs to be inserted - the criteria is to avoid duplicate insert data and since this is batch insert - there is a possible case of unique constraint errors. In this case - we should handle constraint errors right to avoid duplicate insert data (if we loosen constraint). 

In this case - how can we handle the above case mentioned in the description?